# AWS Glue Dynamic_frame with pushdown predicate not filtering correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am writing an script for AWS Glue that is sourced in S3 stored parquet files, in which I am creating a DynamicFrame and attempting to use pushDownPredicate logic to restrict the data coming in.

The table partitions are (in order): *account_id > region > vpc_id > dt*

And the code for creating the dynamic_frame is the following:

```
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = DATABASE_NAME,
    table_name= TABLE_NAME,
    push_down_predicate = "dt='" + DATE + "'")
```

where `DATE = '2019-10-29'`

However it seems that Glue still attempts to read data from other days. Maybe it's because I have to specify a push_down_predicate for the other criteria?

Comment: "However it seems that Glue still attempts to read data from other days". Did you verify this from the logs?

Comment: The output of the logs shows that the following directories are taking into account:
`s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY/dt=2019-07-15
s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY//dt=2019-10-03
s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY//dt=2019-08-27
s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY//dt=2019-10-29
...`


The problem is that old files have different partitions configuration

Comment: Have you tried passing values for all partitions? Because when you pass only date Glue doesn't automatically know from which account_id > region > vpc_id the date has to be pulled from. So try passing all 4 partition values which will then load only one partition to Glue job.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the logs show that the date partition column is marked as "dt" where as in your table it is being referred by the name "date"

**Logs**

```
s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY/dt=2019-07-15 
s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY//dt=2019-10-03 
s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY//dt=2019-08-27 
s3://route/account_id=XXX/region=eu-west-1/vpc_id=YYY//dt=2019-10-29 ...
```

**Your Code**

```
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
database = DATABASE_NAME,
table_name= TABLE_NAME,
push_down_predicate = "date='" + DATE + "'")
```

Change the ***date*** partitions column name to ***dt*** in your table and same in push_down_predicate parameter in the above code.

I also see extra forward slashes in some of the paths in above logs, were these partitions added manually through athena using ALTER TABLE command? If so, I would recommend to use MSCK REPAIR command to load all partitions in the table to avoid such issues. Extra blank slashes in S3 path some times lead to errors while doing ETL through spark.